# 128 bit Miller Rabin Primality test

Tags: c++, bignum, primality-test

I wanted to implement Miller Rabin Primality Test for large numbers. I wanted to know how to deal with such huge numbers in C++. Should I write any special function to store and process those large numbers or care is taken automatically?

Answer (score 3):

You should use an *arbitrary precision* library. Since you only need integers, [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) is a very popular and well-maintained such library. It has a nice C++ interface provided by `<gmpxx.h>`.